Problem on webpack-plugin-vuetify after migration from vue(tify) 2 to 3
I am trying to update a project from vuetify 2 to vuetify 3, naturally, I'm updating vue 2 to vue 3.
I have managed all of the dependencies problems, but I am not sure if I updated all the config files of the projects the good way (I mean the main.js, the vuetify.js etc.), so when I do npm i, I have no problem of dependencies, everything is installed.
But when I hit npm run dev, this error pops up :
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vuetify')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vuetify')
    at private\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-vuetify\index.js:29:54
    at private\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:268:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (private\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:268:26)
    at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (private\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:272:48)
    at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (private\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\PluginAPI.js:132:25)
    at serve (private\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:79:31)
    at Service.run (private\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:262:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Here is the content of the node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-vuetify\index.js at the line 29 :
22 if (isVue3) {
23     if (hasVuetifyPlugin) {
24       const { VuetifyPlugin } = require('webpack-plugin-vuetify')
25 
26       api.chainWebpack(config => {
27         config
28           .plugin('VuetifyPlugin')
29           .use(VuetifyPlugin, [options.pluginOptions.vuetify])
30       })
31     } else if (hasVuetifyLoader) {
32       throw new Error('vuetify-loader is only for use with vuetify 2, replace it with webpack-
33 plugin-vuetify')
34     }
35   } else if (hasVuetifyLoader) {
36     const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
37 
38     api.chainWebpack(config => {
39       config
40         .plugin('VuetifyLoaderPlugin')
41        .use(VuetifyLoaderPlugin)
42     })
43   }

Here is my package.json (of course I have other needed informations in it but I chose to not display them) :
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apexcharts": "^3.50.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "core-js": "^3.37.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "v-offline": "^3.5.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.31",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.2",
    "vue-lodash": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-numerals": "^4.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^4.4.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
    "vuetify": "^3.6.11",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^9.6.0",
    "eslint-config-vuetify": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-lodash": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.27.0",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.77.6",
    "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "stylus": "^0.63.0",
    "stylus-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-eslint-config-vuetify": "^0.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.5.8",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-essentials": "^0.8.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.16"
  }

Here is my main.js :
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import "./plugins";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import { sync } from "vuex-router-sync";
import VueLodash from "vue-lodash";
import lodash from "lodash";
import Vuelidate from "vuelidate";

Vue.use(Vuelidate);

Vue.use(VueLodash, { name: "lo", lodash: lodash });

sync(store, router);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");

And the plugins/vuetify.js :
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#0055A4",
        secondary: "#1480CF",
        tertiary: "#495057",
        accent: "#eb4952",
        error: "#f55a4e",
        info: "#0E264A",
        success: "#5cb860",
        warning: "#ffa21a",
        new_blue: "#009DCC",
        new_orange: "#EA5B0F",
        black_text: "#001737",
        background: "#f3f3f3",
        filter_btn: "#cdd6dc",
        subtitle: "#495463",
        user_square: "#1763aa"
      }
    }
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: "mdi"
  }
});

Can someone help me to understand the problem ?
Thanks in advance for anyone helping
